# How to set SQL default value equals primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tables called `post` and look like below:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════╗
║     post_id   origin_post_id   rev ║
╠════════════════════════════════════╣
║        1          1             1  ║
║        2          1             2  ║
║        3          3             1  ║
║        4          3             2  ║
╚════════════════════════════════════╝
```

`post_id` is primary key and use auto_increment.
I use `origin_post_id` to store the origin post id.

I want to set `origin_post_id` as equal to `post_id` if it is a new post.
How to let me use

```
INSERT INTO POST 
            (POST_ID, 
             ORIGIN_POST_ID, 
             REV) 
VALUES      (NULL, 
             Default, 
             3)
```

What should I do when I create the table?
Is there some ways can get auto_increment key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your above Query

```
INSERT INTO POST 
            (POST_ID, 
             ORIGIN_POST_ID, 
             REV) 
VALUES      (NULL, 
             Default, 
             3)
```

then Run update Query

```
UPDATE POST SET ORIGIN_POST_ID=POST_ID WHERE ORIGIN_POST_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: This will walk over the whole table. It works if you add a null check, but the larger the table, the slower it gets.

Comment: `UPDATE POST SET ORIGIN_POST_ID=POST_ID WHERE ORIGIN_POST_ID IS NULL;`

Comment: i can't find another answer which use trigger now.